# Replace a single character in a Numpy list of strings

Tags: python, numpy, datetime64

I have a Numpy array of datetime64 objects that I need to convert to a specific time format yyyy-mm-dd,HH:MM:SS.SSS 
Numpy has a function called `datetime_as_string` that outputs ISO8601 (yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS.SSS) time, which is extremely close to what I want, the only difference being there is a T where I want a comma.

Is there a way to quickly swap the "T" for a ","? Here is an example data set:

```
offset = np.arange(0, 1000)
epoch = np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000')
time_objects = epoch + offset.astype('timedelta64[ms]')
time_strings = np.datetime_as_string(time_objects)
```

I have had success using a lambda and a list comprehension, but it seems awkward switching back and forth from a Python list to a Numpy array.

```
f = lambda x: x[:10] + ',' + x[11:]
np.array([f(x) for x in time_strings])
```

I know in some cases lambdas can be applied "direct" to a Numpy array, but it doesn't work in this case. `f(time_strings)` produces a TypeError. Any thoughts?

I know I could convert back to a Python datetime (which is the direction I'm coming from) or use Pandas. But the `datetime_as_string` function is really fast and I'd like to stick to Numpy solution.

--- Conclusions based on answers ---
It turns out that Paul's view casting black magic was 75x faster than my list comprehension, and 100x faster than `np.char.replace()`. Here are the results from the three methods (all were initialized with the above dataset, but with 1000000 elements).

```
start = time.time()
time_strings[..., None].view('U1')[..., 10] = ','
print(time.time() - start)
0.016000747680664062 seconds

start = time.time()
f = lambda x: x[:10] + ',' + x[11:]
time_strings = np.array([f(x) for x in time_strings])
print(time.time() - start, 'seconds')
1.1740672588348389 seconds

start = time.time()
time_strings = np.char.replace(time_strings,'T',',')
print(time.time() - start, 'seconds')
1.4980854988098145 seconds
```

Comment: `time_strings = [x.replace('T', ',') for x in time_strings]`

Comment: There's a `np.char.replace`.  While convenient speed isn't much better than a list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use viewcasting to get access to individual characters:

```
time_strings[...,None].view('U1')[...,10] = ','
```

changes `time_strings` in-place.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [309]: np.char.replace(time_strings,'T',',')                                 
Out[309]: 
array(['1970-01-01,00:00:00.000', '1970-01-01,00:00:00.001',
       '1970-01-01,00:00:00.002', '1970-01-01,00:00:00.003',
       '1970-01-01,00:00:00.004', '1970-01-01,00:00:00.005',
       '1970-01-01,00:00:00.006', '1970-01-01,00:00:00.007',
       ....
```

But @PaulPanzer's inplace is much faster (even it is a bit more obscure):

```
In [316]: %%timeit temp=time_strings.copy() 
     ...: temp[...,None].view('U1')[...,10] = ','                                                                      
8.48 µs ± 34.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [317]: timeit np.char.replace(time_strings,'T',',')                          
1.23 ms ± 1.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```